# UIButton linked with IBAction will not work in simulation on physical device nor simulator in Xcode 9.2

Tags: ios, xcode, uibutton, swift4

I added the UIButton with Control + Drag, added the variables and arc4random for randomized numbers, and then used a front function to test my button to make sure it worked. But the button is totally unresponsive and I have no errors in my code.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var randomDiceIndex1 : Int = 0
    var randomDiceIndex2 : Int = 0

    @IBOutlet weak var diceImageView1: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var diceImageView2: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    @IBAction func rollButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {

        randomDiceIndex1 = Int(arc4random_uniform(6))
        randomDiceIndex2 = Int(arc4random_uniform(6))

        print(randomDiceIndex1) //This line of code is what I used to test
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to make sure of the connection between your `storyboard` view controller and `ViewController`, You do that by right-click on `viewController` on `storyboard`.

Comment: I checked to make sure I had a connection and I do. I'm doing a follow-along on Udemy and I re-wrote the code and everything to only get the same results. Could this possibly be a bug?

Comment: It's unlikely to be a bug as this is perfectly standard functionality that people would be crying out about if there was a problem.  Can you share the project (dropbox, etc) or provide more details on how the storyboard is setup.

Comment: I solved the issue today. I just deleted the button and all of the connections I made with it and added a new button. Sorry guys, newbie mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Assign action programmatically.

```
yrBtnOutlet.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self. rollButtonPressed(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: While you certainly can do this there should be no need to and it doesn't help to identify what is causing the original problem.